# Bind click event to disabled link in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<a id="foo" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg disabled" role="button">Link</a>
<a id="bar" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button">Link</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#foo,#bar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```

The alert appears when clicking `#bar`, but not when clicking `#foo`. How can I fix this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VVw8S/

Comment: But this isn't the `disabled` attribute, just a class.

Comment: I guess you included bootstrap.js too, so it may not be "just a class"

Comment: @EoiFirst I checked [the js file](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.js), and the only occurrence of `.disabled` is for the dropdown.

Comment: @GiantDuck this class uses: `pointer-events: none;`. So you could set as CSS rule: `.btn.disabled { pointer-events: all !important; }`  EDIT: not really due to some weird behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/VVw8S/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff I see that `:hover`, `:focus`, and `:active` have their own styles. I copied the normal properties to a more specific selector in my own css file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bootstrap you can read this code:

```
.btn.disabled, .btn[disabled], fieldset[disabled] .btn {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you want to have a disabled button which allowed click events, just overwrite this CSS with `pointer-events: inherit;`. Or simply remove `disabled` in the class of your first link.